# How do I get this to display only the current DATE but within the selected timezone?

Tags: javascript, time

```js
function ctDT(){

var now = new Date(); 
var today = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),  now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
var anHour = 1000 * 60 * 60;
today = new Date(today.getTime() - anHour * 5);

var hours = today.getHours();
var minutes = today.getMinutes();
var seconds = today.getSeconds();

if (hours >= 12){
meridiem = "";
}
else {
meridiem = "";
}


if (minutes<10){
minutes = "0" + minutes;
}
else {
minutes = minutes;
}

if (seconds<10){
seconds = "0" + seconds;
}
else {
seconds = seconds;
}

document.getElementById("ctDT").innerHTML = (hours + ":" + minutes + meridiem);

}

ctDT();
```

```html
<div id="ctDT"></div>
```

I'm new to Javascript, but my friend helped me make this display a time. How do I make it display the date instead?

I can see that there is getUTCDate, but when I replace the whole hours + minute section with only date, it comes out wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Date object method:

```js
var now = new Date();
now.toDateString();

document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = now;
```

```html
<div id="date"></div>
```

Comment: This would have helped but I need to display the date for another timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, all you still want to do is get the date, month, and year.  You can use `getDate()`, `getMonth()`, and `getFullYear`.

Just remember to add `+1` to the month, because JavaScript months start at `0`.

```js
function ctDT(){

var now = new Date();

// Convert date to UTC
var nowUTC = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),  now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());

// Add/Subtract offset from UTC
nowUTC.setHours(nowUTC.getHours()+1);

// Get date parts
var day = nowUTC.getDate();
var month = nowUTC.getMonth();
var year = nowUTC.getFullYear();

var hours = nowUTC.getHours();
var minutes = nowUTC.getMinutes();
var seconds = nowUTC.getSeconds();

if (hours >= 12){
meridiem = "";
}
else {
meridiem = "";
}


if (minutes<10){
minutes = "0" + minutes;
}
else {
minutes = minutes;
}

if (seconds<10){
seconds = "0" + seconds;
}
else {
seconds = seconds;
}

// Display
document.getElementById("ctDT").innerHTML = day + '/' + (month + 1) + '/' + year;
// document.getElementById("ctDT").innerHTML += ' ' + hours + ":" + minutes + meridiem;  //uncomment this line to display time as well

}

ctDT();
```

```html
<div id="ctDT"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, and if I were to change place of month and day, how would I do?
 (day + '/'  + month + 1 +  '/' + year); 

Doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm, time does not seem to update with the correct timezone. my CEST time is on 7/25 but it display 7/24 atm.

Comment: By default JavaScript will use the client's local time, so `Date()` will return your local time.  Just don't convert it to UTC, as your code was doing.  (Keep in mind that this is based on your browser's settings.)

Comment: Correct.  You have to wrap `(month + 1)` in parenthesis when using it in that way.

Comment: I am trying to make it display for CET, not CEST, hence why I can not just use my local date. It is set in UTC so it's not just based on my time. The code works with adjusting the time but not the date, do you know why?

Comment: So you need to convert the date to CET.  I updated the code snippet to convert the date to UTC, and then add the 1 hour offset.

Comment: Your code actually works.  You just need to change the line:  `today = new Date(today.getTime() - anHour * 5);` to add the correct offset (for example: `today.getTime() + anHour * 1`), and it will display the correct date.